# Redis pub/sub - same process listening to one channel

Tags: node.js, express, redis

I have a single Node.js server - I would like for the process to listen to messages sent from itself - this is for testing only. The problem I am having is that when publishing a message to the same process, the subscriber doesn't seem to receive it at all.

I have this setup:

```
var redis = require('redis');

var rcPub = redis.createClient();
var rcSub = redis.createClient();

var message = String('testing123');

rcSub.subscribe('redis_channel@test_overall_health');

rcSub.on('message', function (channel, msgs) {

    console.log(channel,msgs);

});


rcPub.publish('redis_channel@test_overall_health', message);
```

I have one redis client that acts as a subscriber and one as a publisher, which is the way you must do it, but for some reason the messages aren't being received. Is there some limitation that a process can't listen to the messages it publishes? It doesn't seem to make sense. I can verify this code is more or less right because other processes listening to the same channel received the message.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apparently, the `SUBSCRIBE` command is being sent after the `PUBLISH` command.

Node's Redis client queues commands until a connection is established to the Redis server and flushes the queued commands to the server when a `connect` event is received on the socket. The client that initiated the connection first (publisher), will most likely receive the `connect` event first, at which point it will send its queued commands (publish). Because Redis processes commands in a single thread, the subscriber `SUBSCRIBE`s only after the `PUBLISH` command is complete. The other processes are able to receive the messages since they've already subscribed to this channel.

Creating the subscriber client first should work in most cases, albeit a safer approach will be to wait for the subscription to complete before publishing any messages:

```
var redis = require('redis');

var publisher = redis.createClient(),
    subscriber = redis.createClient(),
    message = 'testing123';

subscriber.subscribe('redis_channel@test_overall_health');

subscriber.on('message', function (channel, message) {
    console.log(channel, message);
});

subscriber.on('subscribe', function (channel, count) {
    publisher.publish('redis_channel@test_overall_health', message);
});
```

Comment: cool, thanks, will try this out when I get to work on monday :)

Comment: tried it, what you say appears correct, thanks for figuring this out. this problem that I created for myself exists for all sorts of pub/sub libraries and clearly shows I am a novice here :) this is a problem though because async libraries are consistently deceptive. IMO, subscriber.subscribe should force you to include a callback, that would eliminate the deception. if you need a separate callback "sub.on('subscribe')" then you can implement an eventsEmitter yourself, that would be much better IMO.